# Using python how to access and do arthematic operations on 'n' no.of segments in an array if their coordinates are available?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, image-segmentation, numpy-ndarray

**The following example illustartes my question clearly :**

suppose their is an array **'arr'**

```
 >>import numpy as np
 >>from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks
 >>arr=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]])
  >>arr
  array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
           [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
           [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
           [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

I segmented this array in to 2*2 blocks using :

```
>>img= view_as_blocks(arr, block_shape=(2,2))
>>img
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 1,  2]],

        [[ 3,  4],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 5,  6],
         [ 5,  6]],

        [[ 7,  8],
         [ 7,  8]]],


       [[[ 9, 10],
         [17, 18]],

        [[11, 12],
         [19, 20]],

        [[13, 14],
         [21, 22]],

        [[15, 16],
         [23, 24]]]])
```

I have an other array "cor"

```
>>cor
(array([0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([2, 1, 3], dtype=int64))
```

In "cor" the 1st array ([0,1,1]) gives the coordinates of rows and 2nd array ([2,1,3]) gives the coordinates of corresponding columns in sequential order.

Now my work is to access segments of img whose positional coordinates are [0,2],[1,1]and [1,3] (taken from "cor". x from 1st array and corresponding y from 2nd array) automatically by reading "cor".

In the above example

```
img[0,2]= [[ 5,  6],    img[1,1]= [[11, 12],        img[1,3]=[[15, 16],
           [ 5,  6]],              [19, 20]]                  [23, 24]]
```

then find the mean value of each segment seperately.

```
ie. img[0,2]=5.5  img[1,1]=15.5 img[1,3]=19.5
```

Now, check if its mean values are less than the mean vlaue of whole array "img".
Here, mean value of img is 10.5. hence only mean value of img[0,2] is less than 10.5.
**Therefore finally return coordinate of segment img[0,2] ie [0,2] as output** in sequential order if more segments exists in any other big array.

```
##expected output for above example:
[0,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We simply need to index with `cor` and perform those `mean` computations (along last two axes) and check -

```
# Convert to array format
In [229]: cor = np.asarray(cor)

# Index into `img` with tuple version of `cor`, so that we get all the
# blocks in one go and then compute mean along last two axes i.e. 1,2.
# Then compare against global mean - `img.mean()` to give us a valid
# mask. Then index into columns of `cor with it, to give us a slice of
# valid `cor`. Finally transpose, so that we get per row valid indices set.
In [254]: cor[:,img[tuple(cor)].mean((1,2))<img.mean()].T
Out[254]: array([[0, 2]])
```

---

Another way to set it up, would be to split up the indices -

```
In [235]: r,c = cor

In [236]: v = img[r,c].mean((1,2))<img.mean() # or img[cor].mean((1,2))<img.mean()

In [237]: r[v],c[v]
Out[237]: (array([0]), array([2]))
```

Same as first approach, with the only difference of using split indices to index into `cor` and getting the final indices.

---

Or a compact version -

```
In [274]: np.asarray(cor).T[img[cor].mean((1,2))<img.mean()]
Out[274]: array([[0, 2]])
```

In this solution, we are directly feeding in the original tuple version of `cor`, rest being same as approach#1.

Comment: Thank you so much it works well. Can you please tell what `T[img[cor].mean((1,2))<img.mean()]` is doing in compact version of your answer exactly for better understanding to beginners like me.

Comment: @SaiKiran Added few comments.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really helpful.